# How does a member become a site moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation, participation, election

I have been a member for a long time (close to 5 years). I have a high reputation that is as high as some of the moderators.  Do the moderators vote for new moderators?  If so, is this only done when a moderator retires?

Comment: Please see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=election.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that there are a lot of elections that began on February 14.  But I still do not understand how one gets nominated.

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: It looks to me that I can nominate myself for moderator.  Andre, thank you for the link.  What is my next step?

Comment: You can nominate yourself only when there is an election. FWIW, I don't think reputation really means all that much relative to whether someone would be a good moderator or not.

Comment: I agree with @gung. Above (say) 10000 rep, there are many plausible people.  I would look for a sustained profile of positive contributions, including being firm but fair on difficult issues. We are not looking for saints, but we are looking for good diplomats. gung has the highest reputation of non-moderators but more crucially a record of invariably positive contributions: he would be an excellent moderator. amoeba's work on tags and many other contributions makes him another person I would very much see as a future moderator. Naturally, willingness to stand is essential too.

Comment: @NickCox considering badges and doing moderator tasks, do you consider me a good candidate for moderator? I do think there is certainly some experience that is necessary and it is partially measured by reputation.  I only asked whether or not I was eligible to nominate myself. That seems to have been answered in this thread. I have done some work on tags but I cannot say that I have done more than others on any of these things.  This is not a popularity contest but is campaigning necessary?

Comment: There is a campaign period lasting some days before an election during which people set out a platform and answer questions. Sometimes the questions are sharp. In one recent election as I recall one candidate had as one part of his platform the notion that being elected as a moderator would encourage him to continue as a member!   But the real campaign is on whatever you've done while a member.

Comment: Giving my two cents about the question you asked to Nick Cox (sorry to be nosy, but I think I can help); I don't think you are a good candidate for moderator, **yet**. This is because I think you still need to get acquainted with some mechanisms from how the SE system works (I say this based on some recent questions of yours here in CV Meta. Also, despite you are a member for 5 years, if my memory does not fail I remember you saying you were not active all those years, is that correct?). But I do think you have a great potential to get there.

Comment: @Andre Thank you for the encouragement.  I have always respected your opinion.  I don't ask many questions on CV Meta but I do think those I have written are improving.  I said that I have been a member for nearly five years.  I have only been off the stack exchange sites briefly when I was ill.  I also have spent a lot of time on the Mathematics site.  I hope the CV members will pick me now, otherwise maybe next time.

Comment: @MichaelChernick You seem to be confused: there is no "now". No election is being currently held.

Comment: I did not make it up.  I heard it from someone.

Comment: I see. Well, this was a misinformation.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, where did you hear that? When will the election be?

Comment: I was told that this would happen in April of 2017.